# LWC - Iterating over arrays passed into the component by a parent is ridiculously slow

Tags: lightning-web-components, locker-service

Imagine we have a parent component where we create an array like so:

```
@track stuff = [];

connectedCallback() {
     let newArray = [];

     for (let s = 0; s < 10000; s++) {
          newArray.push({ prop1: 'One' + s, prop2: 'Two' + s, prop3: s, prop4: [s] });
     }

     this.stuff = [...newArray];
}
```

On my system this takes some 5 ms.

now I pass this array to my child component:

```
<c-child-component stuff={stuff}></c-child-component>
```

And in my child component I have a button

```
<lightning-button label="click me" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
```

```
@api stuff; 

handleClick() {
     let newItems = [];

     for (let s = 0; s < this.stuff.length; s++) {
          if (this.stuff[s]['prop3'] % 2 == 0) {
               newItems.push(this.stuff[s]);
          }
     }
}
```

This `handleClick` method takes a whopping 130 seconds on my system, simply iterating through the array.

What is actually happening is aura_prod.js is locking every property on every element in an array and so has to decide if that property is reactive or not. This is painfully slow and basically makes this unusable.

What is the recommended approach for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) methods instead, for this causes the Locker Service security filter method to apply only once. Note that this is a **Locker Service** problem, *not* a **LWC** problem. If you use LWC OSS, you'll find your code would perform perfectly well (as I'll demonstrate below).

```
@api stuff; 

handleClick() {
  let newItems = this.stuff.filter(item => (item.prop3 % 2 == 0));
}
```

I [wrote a demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/0OjEDnMPitH7Sa5ZJPcl/src/app.html) for you. It takes about 18ms for my computer to calculate the new list using my code, 19ms for yours (time may vary a bit, but should be <50ms). But with Locker Service, you should notice probably 20-30ms for my code, and **minutes** for yours. This is normal, and expected.

You must not access individual elements of an `@api` marked variable. Always use either Array.prototype methods, or clone the list first with `let localCopy = [...stuff];` and work on that, instead.

This happens because, for an individual array access, the Locker Service filter has to filter all 10,000 items. So, iterating 10,000 times over 10,000 elements, means a total of 100,000,000 array accesses. Oops.

Comment: Thank you! this helped heaps because i was almost resigned to resorting to something like `JSON.stringify()` in parent and then `JSON.parse()` in child.

Comment: @zaitsman That's technically possible, but rather an annoying workaround. Using a copy in the child is actually the ideal scenario.

Comment: @sfdcfox since it's locker service not LWC, is the same behaviour observable in Aura? Would you know?

Comment: @ChristianSzandorKnapp Yes, Aura does have the same issue, and the same workarounds are suggested.

Answer (score 4):

I had experienced the same a while back, and learned that this is a limitation with locker service as mentioned by @sfdcfox.

You can find the explanation is documented as well:

[Arrays Proxied When Passed to Child Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.security_array_proxy)

> A page that’s using a component that passes a large array of objects through layers of child components can become unresponsive

recommendations by Salesforce are narrowed down to:

- Avoid passing large arrays of objects more than one level down. For example, pass an array from parent to child but no further.
- Divide your data into multiple smaller arrays in the parent component.

personally, I avoid passing large sets of data in between components due to this limitation. Hopefully SF will come up with something...

Comment: +1 Glad to see that's been acknowledged as a limitation in the documentation, didn't know they added that.

Comment: @glls Yeah this is definitely extremely annoying and unfortunately due to the design of my code it's almost inevitable that i need to pass something like hundreds of thousands of rows centrally fetched in parent component to multiple sub components.

Comment: You could try passing your array as a serialized JSON version - that should be much faster.